# PDO method for mysql_fetch_assoc()?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I used to do :

```
$resource = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = " . $id);
$user = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource);
echo "Hello User, your number is" . $user['number'];
```

I read that mysql statements are all deprecated and should not be used.

How can i do this with PDO?

The first line would be :

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = " . $id); // there was an aditional double quote in here.
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
```

What about the mysql_fetch_assoc() function?

I am using php

Comment: The first line would be `$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=:id");` as putting user data in your queries using string concatenation is **dangerous**.

Comment: yeap i know , i made an edit to make clear that i only need the mysql_fetch_assoc() function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` constant 
Usage will be 
`while ($res = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
....
}`
Here's the reference (documentation precisely) : http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: And how now do i refer to the "number" column?

Comment: after `$res` loaded, you can simply call it like `mysql_fetch_assoc`. `$res['number']` would do

Answer (score 1):

All well documentned in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

As example:

```
<?php
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: +1, although I'd say it maps closer to [`fetch`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) than [`fetchAll`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

Comment: Right, but it's just an example that will draw him toward the manual (and searching in it). I prefer to do that instead of giving a complete answer when it's a case like that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice manual [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info).

From which you can learn what you don't need to set fetch mode explicitly with every fetch.
...and even what with PDO you don't need no arrays at all to echo a number:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT number FROM table WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($id));
echo "Hello User, your number is".$stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice tutorial:
http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

```
<?php
   $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
   $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table");
   $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   var_dump($results);
?>
```

Comment: This should be correct, though the fetchAll doesn't really work like mysql_fetch_assoc() which returns one by one row. I'm plussing one it

Comment: @WillyPt I am just giving a general example to show him the syntax, and it is already mentioned like that in the tutorial. Take a look at "Running Simple Select Statements" in the tutorial.

Answer (score -2):

You can use PDO::FETCH_ASSOC for the same.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = :id");
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt->execute();
while($record = $stmt->fetch()) {
   //do something
}
```

You can find a good tutorial [here](http://rationalspace.wordpress.com/2013/05/08/using-pdo-php-data-objects/)